# Is this FindBugs nullpointer dereference error valid for spring-data Specification class?

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, findbugs, null-check

I am getting `"Possible null pointer dereference due to return value of called method"` FindBugs error on following line.

```
Specification spec = Specification.where(idSpec).and(nameSpec)
    .and(typeSpec).and(statusSpec);
```

Specification is Spring data JPA class. Some of its snippets:

```
    @Nullable
    static <T> Specification<T> where(@Nullable Specification<T> spec) {
        return spec == null ? (root, query, builder) -> null : spec;
    }

    @Nullable
    default Specification<T> and(@Nullable Specification<T> other) {
        return composed(this, other, (builder, left, rhs) -> builder.and(left, rhs));
    }
```

Is this valid FindBugs error? How to fix it?

How can I avoid null checks on each and every call of `where` and `and`? As such null checks will reduce readbility of code which currently reads just like a query using method chaining.

Comment: `where` returns a non-null value. It's incorrect to tag it as `@Nullable`.

Comment: Remove the @Nullable annotation?

Comment: That's Spring data JPA classes, I don't own them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring has removed these incorrect `@Nullable` annotations from `Specification` class as part of [DATAJPA-1766](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJPA-1766).

This will work fine now after using the Spring version in which above defect was fixed.

Answer (score 1):

> Is this valid FindBugs error?

Yes it is.

> How to fix it?

Add the tests for `null` or tell FindBugs to be quiet.

> How can I avoid `null` checks on each and every call of where and and? As such null checks will reduce readbility of code which currently reads just like a query using method chaining.

There is no magic bullet for this.  You need to do one of the following:

- add the ugly null checks, or
- code your own replacement<sup>1</sup> for `Specification` where the arguments and results are not `Nullable`, or
- individually suppress any potential bugs found by FindBugs  that you "know" are not real bugs, or
- turn that check off completely.

Note that if you suppress a Findbugs check that is an actual bug, you are liable to get NPEs at runtime.  So the onus would be on you *to use other techniques* to find any (real) bugs in your application could lead to NPEs.  For example, more comprehensive unit and system tests.

---

<sup>1 - I am not sure if this is technically feasible, but you *may* be able to write subclasses of `Specification` and friends, and then change your code to use them instead of the originals.  There will be downsides to doing this ...</sup>

Comment: Thanks for the answer. As, @Andy mentioned `where()` will never return null and should not be marked `@Nullable`. I have raised [DATAJPA-1766](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJPA-1766) to get it removed. If Spring team doesn't accept it, I will go ahead with one of the approaches you have suggested.